# Compress raster GeoTIFF in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, geotiff-tiff

I have a dozen raster (3 bands) files in GeoTIFF format (32bit), which I have downloaded from SentinelHub (sentinel2 satellite imagery).

I try to compress them before I publish them as an Imager Service through ArcGIS Server. I follow the guidelines from this [link](https://grid.gaiaresources.com.au/user-manual/4-my-gis/4-1-manage-my-layers/4-01-8-compress-to-geotiff-format-image-raster/), which makes use of the "Translate (Convert Format)" tool.

The output raster is very small (500kb) and it is all black. I thought I need to calculate statistics for it, but this didnt fix the issue.

Any ideas what could be the issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It may be that your 32 bit image has all the data at the low end of the full 32 bit range.  In that case the image viewer should stretch the actual data range for visualization. Check the statistics of your image with `gdalinfo -stats`. If image is really all black with min=0 and max=0 then something has gone wrong with gdal_translate.